# How to use react-router useHistory hook with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

In my func component I am trying to use `history.push` in this way:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

interface Props {
  question: Question;
  selectedAnswer: SelectedOption | undefined;
}

const LastScreen: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  ...
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (progress === 100) {
      const id = uuid();
      history.push({
        pathname: `/p/${id}`,
        state: { userAnswers },
      });
    }
  }, [progress, userAnswers, history]);
  ...
};
```

but it gives an error:

`Argument of type '{ pathname: string; state: { userAnswers: UserAnswers | undefined; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'To'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not exist in type 'PartialPath'.ts(2345)`

How to fix it?

Comment: after trying to fix it I found the problem appears when using custom history, like ```import history from 'history';``` and then ```<Router history={history}>...</Router>```
So when I replaced it with ```<BrowserRouter>...</BrowserRouter>``` the problem disappeared.

Comment: Note: `useHistory` is old (v5), now (v6), `const navigate = useNavigate(); 
navigate('/')` is used. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70274942/6702598

Answer (score 0):

The `useHistory` hook gives you access to the history instance that you may use to navigate.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
  

let history = useHistory();
```

Answer (score 0):

The react-router documentation says the following on the `history.push` function:

> push(path, [**state**]) - (function) Pushes a new entry onto the history stack

I'm not sure what variable type `userHistory` is, but it needs to be a state variable. I can tell it isn't because you aren't importing useState. Import useState with useEffect like this:

`import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';`

And declare the variable like this:

`const [ userHistory, setUserHistory ] = useState();`

Then you can set userHistory:

`setUserHistory("foo");`

#### Sources:

[React Router history doucmentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history)

[ReactJS useState documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#adding-state-to-a-component)