# Passing state by history.push({..}) in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I used `history.push` to redirect to my desired url and passed an information via the included state to the next route like this:

```js
const history = useHistory()
history.push({
   pathname: '/someurl/',
   state: {
      foo: bar
   }
})
```

and in JavaScript this worked absolutely as expected. Now I am migrating this file to TypeScript and I am getting the following error:

```js
Argument of type '{ pathname: string; state: { foo: bar; }; }'
is not assignable to parameter of type 'To'.

Object literal may only specify known properties, and
'state' does not exist in type 'PartialPath'
```

For some reason he thinks that I only pass a pathname without a state right?
Does anyone know how to fix that?

Comment: Do you mean `pushState` not `push`...?

Comment: Uhmm, I guess it should be `.push` at least thats what I did in js when it worked.

Comment: The `history` object doesn't have a `push`, did you have some lib that added it?

Comment: yeah i accessed it by using `useHistory` and the returned history object doesn't have `pushState`

Comment: Ah!! `useHistory` is not the same as `window.history`, so that might explain things.   What version of definitelyTyped are using for react-router.?

Comment: I am using `5.3.2` .. found this stackoverflow topic with the same problem but his proposed solution doesn't change anything for me.. :(
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792224/how-to-use-react-router-usehistory-hook-with-typescript

Comment: Okay, figured it out and I would be easier to solve if I followed the hints from vsc...
`history.push('/someurl/', {foo: bar})` works

Comment: Using  react-router `5.2.1` works for me too,  How are you getting version `5.3.2`?.  As I can tell 5.2.1 is the latest before version 6..

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo :D `5.2.1` but anyway it works now :) thanks

Comment: @Keith Unless there's been another version bump in the last few days v5.3.0 is the latest v5 version. The API didn't change from v5.2.1 though.

Comment: You seem to be using a custom history object in your project, can you confirm what version of `history` package you are using and how you are configuring your router? I suspect the code is correct (*it sounds like it works as expected*) but Typescript might not be referring to the correct version of `history`.

Comment: Okay I checked again and I am using `"react-router-dom": "^5.2.1"` and `"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2"`.. but the solution i mentioned above works fine :)

Comment: And what about the `history` version and router usage? The "standard" `history.push` takes two arguments. I think you should be on v4.x of `history`, v4.10.1 is latest v4.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was nonsense what I was posting. Somehow thought of react-router-dom .. my history version is `"history": "^5.0.0"`

Comment: Try reverting back to a v4 version of `history` package.

Answer (score -1):

Same issue resolved by after trying to fix it I found the problem appears when using custom history, like import history from `'history'`; and then `<Router history={history}>...</Router>` So when I replaced it with `<BrowserRouter>...</BrowserRouter>` the problem disappeared.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).